# Writing response for Pact test for Grpc

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, grpc-java, pact

Hi I am trying to use Pact to perform test between my services

The problem is that the response from my service provider is quite large and have complex structure

I tried to follow the Calculator example

```
        "response", List.of(
        Map.of(
          "value", "matching(number, 12)"
        )
      )
```

but for my case, its will be a lot of Map.of and List.of

So, my question is there any other way to write contract response, or is there any document that guild me write pact dsl
Thanks